# Why can the inner product be a criteria for the orthogonality of a matrix

Tags: lie-groups, orthogonality

I would like to verify if the matrix
$\left( \begin{array}{rr} a&b\\c&d \end{array}\right)$ is a Lorentz transformation.

Lorentz Transformations are orthogonal together with the inner product $(x,y) = x_0y_0 -x_iy_i$ . If $a =0$ and $d=0$ then the Matrix is invertible and therefor orthogonal. My script now states that because $(Lx,Lx) \leq 0$ for $x = \left( \begin{array}{r} 1\\0 \end{array}\right)$ L is not a Lorentz transformation for the case that $a=0$.

I would like to understand why the inner product of the resulting vector with itself has to be greater $0$ to be orthogonal?

Comment: That is not an inner product.

Comment: @copper.hat it is not a (positive definite) inner product, but for Lorentz transformations you do want to use this (maybe one should just say) bilinear form.

Answer (score 1):

the Lorenz transformations in this dimension, having positive determinant and positive trace, are
$$
L =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cosh t & \sinh t \\
\sinh t & \cosh t
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The property required is
$$L^T H L = H,  $$
where
$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
You may also negate the right column of $L$ or the left column or both. The version I gave is symmetric.